# Eclimd: Can't locate files when run from vim

Tags: java, vim, eclim

I have an Eclipse project:

```
myProject/
       |--src/
       |   |--MyClass.java
       |
       |--bin/
           |--MyClass.class
           |--data.dat
```

`MyClass` reads from `data.dat`. When I edit `MyClass.java` and run using `:Java` from within `vim`, I get a bunch of errors:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.dat (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
```

If I navigate to `myProject/bin` and run the classes there using `java MyClass`, I'm able to read the `data.dat` file.

Where do I set the location of the files I'm trying to open so that they're relative to the *compiled* Java, not relative to my `*.java` files? It doesn't seem to be in the `.classpath` file.

As a secondary question: I'm having issues finding the answer to this because I don't quite know what to search for. `java runtime file locations` doesn't work. What keywords describe this problem so I can find the answer for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because the default path isn't the bin folder but the project folder itself. Try to move your file to the project folder or change its path within the program.

You could also pass the file via commandline arguments but this can cause some other problems as you might already know.